# React Material UI select component Issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

If you go to Select component in MUI
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/

and open any select dropdowns.
You can notice that you will not be able to interact with page until you close that dropdown.

Is there any solution to this ?
Even not able to scroll after I open dropdown

P.S. I don't want to use NativeSelect.

Answer (score -1):

You could potentially have an event listener for scrolling (see documentation):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event

Then programmatically close the select when that happens, using the 'open' tag on the select component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by having relevant code snippets to solve the OP's problem instead of just a link to documentation.